# Wordpress/Elementor Popup Issues

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am currently working on a website - [www.ruskinfelix.com](http://www.ruskinfelix.com)

1. In this website, there is a navigation bar with multiple options. I've added a popup to 'Services' and 'Insights' that expand to different other buttons in that popup. Each button is attached to another popup that displays that button's submenu which again contain multiple buttons with links to different pages in the website. Now when I click on any of the button with the links to different pages, the first popup that opened after clicking 'Services' or 'Insights' closes automatically but the second popup whose button I just pressed does not close automatically but closes after the new page to which the button was linked to gets loaded fully.

2. In the same first popup inside 'Services' or 'Insights', when I click on any of the buttons, their respective popup opens. Once this happens, I am not able to click on another button to open another popup directly. I have to close all the popups and navigate from scratch in order to click a new button. This might be happening due to the second popup being displayed over the first popup, therefore not allowing me to click on any of the buttons of the first popup

Any help would be highly appreciated!